# Cчетчик на слайд и показывать юзеру номер слайда и количество слайдов

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Уже есть слайдер на бутстрапе, слайды генерируются с JSONа, нужно поставить счетчик на каждый слайд и вывести на экран.

```js
$.get('apiCall')
      .then(function(response) {
          var $carousel = $('#carouselExampleIndicators');
          var $carouselInner = $carousel.find('.carousel-inner');

          response.data.forEach(function(item, i) {
            var template = '';

            if(i === 0) {
              template = '<div class="carousel-item active">';
            } else {
              template = '<div class="carousel-item">';
            }
            
            template += '<img class="d-block w-100" src="' + item.image + '" alt="Second slide">'; 
            template += '<div class="carousel-caption">';
            template += '<h5>' + item.title_a + '</h5>';
            template += '<p class="summary">' + item.summary + '</p>';
            template += '</div>';
            template += '</div>';

            $carouselInner.append(template);
          })

          $carousel.carousel();
      })
```

```css
.summary {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="slider slideshow d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 mb-3">
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide w-50" data-ride="carousel">
  <span class="pagingInfo">-</span>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
   <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
   <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Вы взяли готовую библиотеку. Почему не спросите на том сайте, откуда взяли? И после того, как создали пост, попробуйте воспроизвести код в описании вопроса, чтобы проверить, нормально ли он работает.

Comment: Поправил код, у бутстрапа нет такой функции

Comment: Что такое счетчик?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавлена эта строчка, чтобы определить общее количество:

`var qty = response.data.length;`

И эта строчка вначале, чтобы перед каждой картинкой напихать span с записью. Надо было знать, что `i` внутри функции является номером очередного элемента... и его можно использовать. Останется как-то дать нормальный стиль классу `.count` (смотрите в сторону positon: fixed; background-color: white; top: 0; left: 0);

`template += '<span class="count">' + (i+1) + ' / ' + qty + '</span>`

```js
$.get('apiCall')
      .then(function(response) {
          var $carousel = $('#carouselExampleIndicators');
          var $carouselInner = $carousel.find('.carousel-inner');
          var qty = response.data.length;
          response.data.forEach(function(item, i) {
            var template = '';

            if(i === 0) {
              template = '<div class="carousel-item active">';
            } else {
              template = '<div class="carousel-item">';
            }
            
            template += '<span class="count">' + (i+1) + ' / ' + qty + '</span><img class="d-block w-100" src="' + item.image + '" alt="Second slide">'; 
            template += '<div class="carousel-caption">';
            template += '<h5>' + item.title_a + '</h5>';
            template += '<p class="summary">' + item.summary + '</p>';
            template += '</div>';
            template += '</div>';

            $carouselInner.append(template);
          });
          
          $carousel.carousel();
      })
```

```css
.count {font-size: 28px; position: absolute;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="slider slideshow d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 mb-3">
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide w-50" data-ride="carousel">
  <span id="count"></span>
  <span class="pagingInfo">-</span>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
   <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
   <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут есть про события карусели https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

В итоге можно получить такое (вариант с "счетчиком", вынесенным за слайды):

```js
$.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/152ni8')
      .then(function(response) {
          var $carousel = $('#carouselExampleIndicators');
          var $carouselInner = $carousel.find('.carousel-inner');

          response.data.forEach(function(item, i) {
            var template = '';

            if(i === 0) {
              template = '<div class="carousel-item active">';
            } else {
              template = '<div class="carousel-item">';
            }
            
            template += '<img class="d-block w-100" src="' + item.image + '" alt="Second slide">'; 
            template += '<div class="carousel-caption">';
            template += '<h5>' + item.title_a + '</h5>';
            template += '<p class="summary">' + item.summary + '</p>';
            template += '</div>';
            template += '</div>';

            $carouselInner.append(template);
          })

          $carousel.carousel();
          
          var totalSlides = response.data.length;
          $('#counter').text('1/' + totalSlides);
          $carousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
            $('#counter').text((e.to+1) + '/' + totalSlides);
          });
      })
```

```css
.summary {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="slider slideshow d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 mb-3">
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide w-50" data-ride="carousel">
  <span class="pagingInfo">-</span>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
   <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
   <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="counter">0/0</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```